# Instalacion de node duplicada

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

Consulta en Ubuntu 18, quiero actualizar a la ultima version de node y npm, para luego actualizar angular cli. El tema es que encuentro 2 versiones de node preinstaladas.
Si hago un node -v, me tira 6.11.14
y si hago sudo node -v (con sudo), me tira 8.10.0

no termino de entender que versión finalmente es la que usa el sistema operativo para las funciones de angular. Y lo que menos entiendo es como actualizar la versión 6.11.14 que tengo aquí, ya que entiendo que los comandos para actualizar van con sudo, y si hago eso me actualiza la version 8.10.0, no la de 6.11.14.

Answer (score 1):

- Elimina la instalación local ejecutando : `npm uninstall node`
- Instala una versión global usando el atributo global: `sudo npm install -g node`
- Ejecuta `node -v` a ver que versión te lanza ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Haz instalado una version con sudo y la otra version se encuentra instalada localmente con tu user normal.

Corre: `ll / usr / bin / node` si este archivo existe, simplemente corre `rm / usr / local / bin / node` del usuario normal.

Si ejecuta node del usuario normal, probablemente verás que apunta al directorio de bin > local del usuario.

Puedes probar:

```
/ usr / local / bin / node
```

Esto significa que el usuario normal ha instalado otra versión de nodo localmente.

Para permitir que la misma versión de node se aplique a todos los usuarios, este comando debe mostrar usr bin (no local).

De la siguiente manera:

```
/ usr / bin / node
```

borrando el enlace de `/ usr / local / bin / node` comenzará automáticamente a usar

> `/ usr / bin / node`